# How to count selected UITableView rows in Swift. Optional in indexPathForSelectedRow

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview, swift

I'm trying to get number of selected rows in my tableView:

```
self.tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)

tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
   updateCount()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    updateCount()
}

func updateCount(){

  let list = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows() as [NSIndexPath]

  println(list.count)
```

Everything works good until something is selected. But when there is no selected row, app crashes with "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".
I think it is because selection is nil, but how to write this code with Optionals? I tried 
many ways but app still crashes when I uncheck all selection.

Comment: but why you need to do this ?

Comment: For example I can have a button "Delete" displaying number of items to delete.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you're on the right track.  The error is happening because no rows are selected. Use conditional binding like so:

```
func updateCount(){        
    if let list = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows() as? [NSIndexPath] {
        println(list.count)
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI no () after indexPathsForSelectedRows

Comment: Be careful the block is not called if list is empty.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do

```
func updateCount(){
   if let list = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
        print(list.count)
   }
 }
```